# Help with Example 5.18 in Rudin's PMA

Tags: real-analysis

[image: text]
Rudin showed a counterexample that L'Hospital's rule fails when it comes to complex-valued functions. My question is how can we get $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$
using the fact that $|e^{it}|=1$ for all real $t$?
I would appreciate if you could explain in details. Thank you!

Comment: He just wants to show that is bounded so the product with a function that has limit 0, has also limit 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\frac  {g(x)} {f(x)} -1|=| xe^{ix^{2}}| =|x| \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.  So $\frac  {g(x)} {f(x)} $ tends to $1$. Hence $\frac  {f(x)} {g(x)} $ also tends to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact that
$$ \frac{|x|}{|x| + |x^2 e^{i/x^2}|} \leq \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right| \leq \frac{|x|}{|x| - |x^2 e^{i/x^2}|} $$
and squeeze theorem.

Comment: I'm wondering if we need to take absolute value on $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.

Comment: Yes. I will amend that, thank you.

Comment: I have another question. We can so get $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=1$. But does that mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$?

Comment: @XiangdongMeng You are right. This answer is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x)=x(1+xe^{i/x^2})\to \\\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{1+xe^{i/x^2}}\sim 1-(xe^{i/x^2})+(xe^{i/x^2})^2-(xe^{i/x^2})^3+...\\
x \to 0 ,|e^{it}|=1 \implies 1-\underbrace{(xe^{i/x^2})+(xe^{i/x^2})^2-(xe^{i/x^2})^3+...}_{\to 0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $|e^{it} |=1$ for all real $t$, we see that $$\lim_{x→0} e^{ix^2 } =1.$$
Or, $$\lim_{x→0} e^{ix^2 } =\lim_{x→0} (\cos x^2+i\sin x^2) =1.$$
Then
$$\lim_{x→0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x→0} \frac{x}{x+x^{2} e^{ix^2 }}=\lim_{x→0} \frac{1}{1+xe^{ix^2}}=1.$$